# Why "Remarked the fish" works? Why not "The fish remarked"?

Tags: meaning, grammar

I read a story, called *The Little Fish*. But I don't understand why the following sentence use ‘Remarked’ began. Usually, sentences always begin with a noun.

> “I can imagine!” remarked the fish.

I'm confusing about the structure of this sentence. Why don't author uses "The fish remarked."? I think the order is matter.

Comment: Usually, after a quotation such as, "I can't believe he did that!" **exclaimed** the boy., we use a lowercase letter to begin the following sentence since it describes the quotation; therefore, it should be, "I can't imagine!" **remarked** the fish.

Comment: The writer used that word order because he liked it better.  If you're writing a story you can use the other order.  They mean the same thing, but one or the other may better fit the "tone" the author seeks.

Answer (score 1):

You see this construct a lot in literature, particular among quotes within a dialogue. It's not uncommon to see this order flip-flopped within a lengthy dialogue, partly (I believe) to make the flow seem less repetitious.

For example, from *Charlotte's Web*, by E.B. White:

> Mr. Arable stopped walking.
>
> "Fern," **he said** gently, "you will have to learn to control yourself."
>
> "Control myself?" **yelled Fern**. "This is a matter of life and death, and you talk about _controlling myself." Tears ran down her cheeks and she took hold of the ax and tried to pull it out of her father's hand.
>
> "Fern," **said Mr. Arable**, "I know more about raising a litter of pigs than you do. A weakling makes trouble. Now run along!"
>
> "But it's unfair," **cried Fern**. "The pig couldn't help being born small, could it? If I had been very small at birth, would you have killed me?"
>
> Mr. Arable smiled. "Certainly not," **he said**, looking down at his daughter with love. "But this is different. A little girl is one thing, a little runty pig is another."
>
> "I see no difference," **replied Fern**, still hanging on to the ax. "This is the most terrible case of injustice I ever heard of."
>
> A queer look came over John Arable's face. He seemed almost ready to
>   cry himself.
>
> "All right," **he said**. "You go back to the house and I will bring the runt when I come in. I'll let you start it on a bottle, like a baby. Then you'll see what trouble a pig can be."

As a footnote, I believe it's customary to put pronouns first, as was done here; *said he* is not nearly as common as *he said*. However, the *replied Fern* in this dialogue could have just as easily been *Fern replied*.

Comment: This is true, but *said he* is not wrong just because it is not all that common anymore.

Comment: @Nick - I never said it was wrong, but thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I know you didn't, J.R. I was just clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

It's called inversion or sometimes anastrophe.  Inversion is when we reverse the normal "subject-verb" construction to form a "verb-subject" construction:

> "I can imagine!" said **he**.
>
> "I am neither a kind man, nor **am I** a fool."
>
> "**Were I** a very rich man, I would buy a yacht and sail the *ocean blue*."
>   ("ocean blue" is also inverted here: adjective-noun becomes
>   noun-adjective)
>
> "**Should he** have any questions, he can call me at this number."

Comment: *"I can answer this!"* remarked Nick.

Comment: Yes, "remarked **Nick**" means "remarked **he**".

Comment: There are problems with inversion that mess with many native speakers. For instance, "There **are you**" is how it should be said since we say, "There are five people (there **are they**)", but most people switch it back to "There **you are**" so as not to have weird constructions like this. "There **am I** in the picture" thus becomes, "There **I am** in the picture."

Comment: This is also where the confusion with "It's **me**" has come from. In correct Modern English, it should be "It **is I**", but normally this is not said unless we have a relative clause following: "It **is I** who will end up doing all of the work."  This is a misconstruction of the older sense in Middle English (if I remember correctly) of "It **am I**".

Comment: In modern English, it should be 'It's me.' Pullum himself has said "If there's a ring at the door and when you ask 'Who is it?' the reply is 'It is I', send them packing. It's not somebody you want to meet." [paraphrased] " 'I can imagine!' said he" is another weirdness marker.

Comment: Okay, well, it should be, "It is I", but we know that that's not how it's often said except when a relative clause is used. I just heard someone say on a TV show, "It's not I..." followed by a relative clause as I was typing this answer out 8 hours ago. My point is that it is a misconstruction of Middle English, "It **am I**", which interplays with this whole explanation of "*said he*".